# A homework is about use macro

Tags: c

This questions is about my homework.
This topic is need to use like:

```
#define GENERIC_MAX(type)\
type type##_max(type x, type y)\
{\
    return x > y ? x : y;\
}
```

The content of the question is to make this code run normally:

```
#include <stdio.h>

GenerateShowValueFunc(double)
GenerateShowValueFunc(int)

int main()
{

    double i = 5.2;
    int j = 3;

    showValue_double(i);
    showValue_int(j);

}
```

The result of the operation is like this:

```
i=5.2000
j=3
```

And this code is my current progress, but there are have problems:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define printname(n) printf(#n);

#define GenerateShowValueFunc(type)\
type showValue_##type(type x)\
{\
    printname(x);\
    printf("=%d\n", x);\
    return 0;\
}

GenerateShowValueFunc(double)
GenerateShowValueFunc(int)

int main()
{

    double i = 5.2;
    int j = 3;

    showValue_double(i);
    showValue_int(j);

}
```

I don’t know how to make the output change with the type, and I don’t know how to display the name of the variable. OAO

---

This original task description:
Please refer to ShowValue.c below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

GenerateShowValueFunc(double)
GenerateShowValueFunc(int)

int main()
{

    double i = 5.2;
    int j = 3;

    showValue_double(i);
    showValue_int(j);

}
```

Through [GenerateShowValueFunc(double)] and [GenerateShowValueFunc(int)] these two lines macro call, can help us to generated as [showValue_double( double )] and [showValue_int( int )]  function, And in main() function called. The execution result of this program is as follows:

```
i=5.2000
j=3
```

Please insert the code that defines GenerateShowValueFunc macro into the appropriate place in the ShowValue.c program, so that this program can compile and run smoothly.

Comment: The C language does not provide support that makes it easy to work with types generically. This is not a good homework assignment for an introductory C course. What is the name of the course? You can create some type-flexible code using `_Generic`. If so, the course should have taught about `_Generic`; you would not be expected to have to discover it for an assignment.

Comment: Perhaps the homework assignment is just to make the `GENERIC_MAX` macro, and you are supposed to demonstrate and test that macro by using specific separate code for `int`, and `double`, not by writing generic code for the demonstration and test?

Comment: You might need one macro more that takes the name of the variable to show and use it with the stringizing operator.

Comment: It is an ill-advised use of a macro IMO.  Why do they teach this stuff, when no professional developer would consider this in any way "normal".

Comment: What relevance has the `GENERIC_MAX` macro to this question?

Comment: @thebusybee that is what the `printname` macro does.

Comment: @Clifford The teacher hopes that we can use similar usage to complete.

Comment: But it prints "x", not "i" or "j"... Or am I wrong?

Comment: @thebusybee You are right - I am going code-blind!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your English is fine. Short clear sentences. One of them a very appreciated clear statement that it is homework-related. I wish for more questions like that. (I removed your self assessment, even if it were correct it would not help. People notice bad English without help. And they are expected to tolerate as long as the meaning is clear enough.)

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank!! (But I still use Google Translate a lot QwQ)

Comment: I see; but `GENERIC_MAX` does not have type dependent side-effect output, so it is less than helpful as an example.

Comment: @Scott Wang - You misunderstood your homework task. Post the original task description, and one can tell the point of your misunderstanding. The posted requirements are impossible to meet. All given answers deviate from the stated requirements.

Comment: @Armali But original task description is not English OAO

Comment: One might be able to translate it.

Comment: @Armali So I just type the original text up?

Comment: Any text here needs to be translated to English.

Comment: It would be okay for me, but someone else might complain (there's nearly always someone who complains); if you want to avoid this, feed the text through Google Translate.

Comment: By the way, OAO - Odessey and Oracle? Orbiting Astronomical Observatory? Otkrytoje Akzionernoje Obschtschestwo?

Comment: @Armali OAO < Just a kaomoji

Comment: I don't know why printfname() function always print x not i or j.

Comment: I wouldn't know why it could ever print anything else than _x_, if it were so.

Comment: That can be achieved with another level of macro expansion. Doing that looks weird. I consider it unneeded here. @Armali and Scott Wang.

Comment: @Yunnosch - Of course - I only referred to Scott Wang's application of `printfname()`. You explained it well in your comment below Clifford's (deleted) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing the shown C-code (i.e. only doing macros), which I consider a requirement, the following code has the required output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define showValue_double(input) \
showValueFunc_double(#input"=%.4f\n" , input)

#define showValue_int(input) \
showValueFunc_int(#input"=%d\n" , input)



#define GenerateShowValueFunc(type) \
void showValueFunc_##type(const char format[], type input)\
{\
    printf(format, input); \
}

/* ... macro magic above;      */
/* unchangeable code below ... */

GenerateShowValueFunc(double)
GenerateShowValueFunc(int)

int main()
{

    double i = 5.2;
    int j = 3;

    showValue_double(i);
    showValue_int(j);

}
```

Output:

```
i=5.2000
j=3
```

Note that I created something of a lookup-table for type-specific format specifiers. I.e. for each type to be supported you need to add a macro  `#define showValue_ ...`. This is also needed to get the name of the variable into the output.

This uses the fact that two "strings" are concatenated by C compilers, i.e. `"A""B"` is the same as `"AB"`. Where `"A"` is the result of `#input`.
The rest, i.e. the required function definition is very similar to the teacher-provided example, using the `##` operator.

Note, this is if the variable name has to correctly be mentioned in the output.
With out the `i =`  things would be easier and would more elegantly use the generated functions WITHOUT having the called `showValue_double(i);` be explicit macros. I.e. the functions generated are 1:1 what is called from `main()`. I think that might be what is really asked. Let me know if you want that version.

Comment: I did something similar to your `#define printname(n) printf(#n);` but using printf inside does not really work...

Comment: I tried it many times and it didn’t work.

Comment: I think your answer is the closest to the question.

Comment: I think so too (no surprise...). But for learning beyond the assignment I recommend to also study the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

A quick & dirty solution would be:

```
type showValue_##type(type x)\
{\
    const char* double_fmt = "=%f\n";\
    const char* int_fmt = "=%d\n";\
    printname(x);\
    printf(type##_fmt, x);\
    return 0;\
}
```

The compiler will optimize out the variable that isn't used, so it won't affect performance. But it might yield warnings "variable not used". You can add null statements like  `(void)double_fmt;` to silence it.

---

Anyway, this is all very brittle and bug-prone, it was never recommended practice to write macros like these. And it is not how you do generic programming in modern C. You can teach your teacher how, by showing them the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void double_show (double d)
{
  printf("%f\n", d);
}

void int_show (int i)
{
  printf("%d\n", i);
}

#define show(x) _Generic((x),\
  double: double_show,       \
  int:    int_show) (x) // the x here is the parameter passed to the function

int main()
{
  double i = 5.2;
  int j = 3;

  show(i);
  show(j);
}
```

This uses the modern C11/C17 standard `_Generic` keyword, which can check for types at compile-time. The macro picks the appropriate function to call and it is type safe. The caller doesn't need to worry which "show" function to call nor that they pass the correct type.

Comment: I think implementing a macro to cover `GenerateShowValueFunc(double)` and `GenerateShowValueFunc(int)` is relevant part of the assignment. But that might only be my reading.

Comment: Otherwise this solution has impressed me with a feature I did not know about before.